# formvalidation.io prevent form submit even if form is valid

Tags: bootstrap-4, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I'm using formvalidation.io to validate my form and it works perfectly.
But I need to prevent form submit even if it is validated.

I tried thid part of code but it doesn't work:

```
const fv = FormValidation.formValidation(
.....
).on('core.form.valid', function (e) {
if ($('#origine').val() === "I") {
    if (!$('input[name="addressees"]').val()) {
        alert("Error");
        fv.updateFieldStatus('subject','Invalid');
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

I also tried this one:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But it doesn't work too.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: can you also include the plugins being used here?

Answer (score 2):

Just comment defaultSubmit plugins

```
plugins: {
        trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
        // Bootstrap Framework Integration
        bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
        // Validate fields when clicking the Submit button
        submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
        // Submit the form when all fields are valid
        // defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
    },
```

it worked for me.